# Find out if the user in specific region using GPS data

Tags: java, android, gps, geolocation, collision-detection

I want to find out if the user in specific region using GPS data and consider with accuracy info to reduce error, because the program will prompt an alert if user definitely out of the region.

GPS sensor return latitude, longitude and accuracy(in meter), I can draw a circle using those data:

```
135.500908,34.661964,30.0
```

There're array of coordinates in sequence represent the specific region:

```
135.500350,34.667011
135.506101,34.666853
135.505972,34.663076
135.505135,34.663111
135.504942,34.662387
135.504084,34.662440
135.504062,34.663146
135.502968,34.663217
135.502689,34.663764
135.502431,34.664205
135.502110,34.664646
135.501680,34.665105
135.501509,34.665246
135.500844,34.665229
135.500371,34.665511
```

My idea is to find out if any collisions of the polygon with the circle by using line-circle collisions detection algorithm, but it looks something wrong in my code, and seems I can't directly use that info due to radius/degree, could anyone help me out? Or let me know if any more simple solution?

```
    public static boolean possiblyInside(List<Double> arrayX, List<Double> arrayY, double locationX, double locationY, double locationAccuracy) {
    if (arrayX.size() != arrayY.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array length not equal");
    }

    boolean anyCircleLineIntersection = false;
    if (arrayX.size() > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayX.size(); i++) {
            double p1x = i == 0 ? arrayX.get(arrayX.size() - 1) : arrayX.get(i - 1);
            double p1y = i == 0 ? arrayY.get(arrayY.size() - 1) : arrayY.get(i - 1);
            double p2x = arrayX.get(i);
            double p2y = arrayY.get(i);

            if (circleLineIntersection(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, locationX, locationY, locationAccuracy)) {
                anyCircleLineIntersection = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return anyCircleLineIntersection;
}

private static boolean circleLineIntersection(double p1X, double p1Y, double p2X, double p2Y, double centerX, double centerY, double locationAccuracy) {
    double rad = (180 / Math.PI);
    double r = (locationAccuracy / 1000);

    p1X = p1X * rad;
    p1Y = p1Y * rad;
    p2X = p2X * rad;
    p2Y = p2Y * rad;
    centerX = centerX * rad;
    centerY = centerY * rad;

    // Transform to local coordinates
    double localP1X = p1X - centerX;
    double localP1Y = p1Y - centerY;
    double localP2X = p2X - centerX;
    double localP2Y = p2Y - centerY;

    // Pre-calculate this value. We use it often
    double pDiffX = localP2X - localP1X;
    double pDiffY = localP2Y - localP1Y;

    double a = (pDiffX) * (pDiffX) + (pDiffY) * (pDiffY);
    double b = 2 * ((pDiffX * localP1X) + (pDiffY * localP1Y));
    double c = (localP1X * localP1X) + (localP1Y * localP1Y) - (r * r);

    double delta = b * b - (4 * a * c);
    return delta >= 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Just to make it clear - you want to determine if the user is in a specific region and prompt an alert if the user is out of the region, right?

Comment: Yes, but no prompt if the user is "possibly inside", so I don't want to use point-in-polygon because it is hard to consider with GPS accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for Todor Kostov's answer.

I know Android has provided Geofencing API, but it is not a perfect fit for my situation due to its implementation and limitations, and I would like to sync the algorithm with iOS version app as well. (Even I know the algorithm are not good as iOS or Android provided, and it also looks a bit silly).

Finally, I solved the problem in this way:

1. Ensure current location not inside the polygon (use point-in-polygon algorithm)
2. Loop through all line segment of the region polygon, find out the
   closest coordinate(PointA) to the current location(PointB)
3. Calculate the distance between PointA and PointB, convert it to meter(X)
4. If X > location accuracy (also in meter), the user is definitely out of the particular region

*p.s. I'm not good at math and geolocation, point out if any incorrect*

```
public static boolean possiblyInside(List<Double> arrayX, List<Double> arrayY, double locationX, double locationY, double locationAccuracy) {
    if (arrayX.size() != arrayY.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array length not equal");
    }

    if (arrayX.size() < 3) {
        return false;
    }

    double minimumDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayX.size(); i++) {
        double p1x = i == 0 ? arrayX.get(arrayX.size() - 1) : arrayX.get(i - 1);
        double p1y = i == 0 ? arrayY.get(arrayY.size() - 1) : arrayY.get(i - 1);
        double p2x = arrayX.get(i);
        double p2y = arrayY.get(i);

        Coordinate closest = getClosestPointOnLine(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, locationX, locationY);
        double currentDistance = distanceMeterBetweenPoints(closest.latitude, closest.longitude, locationX, locationY);
        if (currentDistance < minimumDistance) {
            minimumDistance = currentDistance;
        }
    }

    return (minimumDistance <= locationAccuracy);
}

private static Coordinate getClosestPointOnLine(double sx1, double sy1, double sx2, double sy2, double px, double py) {
    double xDelta = sx2 - sx1;
    double yDelta = sy2 - sy1;

    if ((xDelta == 0) && (yDelta == 0)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Line start equals line end");
    }

    double u = ((px - sx1) * xDelta + (py - sy1) * yDelta) / (xDelta * xDelta + yDelta * yDelta);

    final Coordinate closestPoint;
    if (u < 0.0) {
        closestPoint = new Coordinate(sx1, sy1);
    } else if (u > 1.0) {
        closestPoint = new Coordinate(sx2, sy2);
    } else  {
        closestPoint = new Coordinate((int) Math.round(sx1 + u * xDelta), (int) Math.round(sy1 + u * yDelta));
    }

    return closestPoint;
}

public static double distanceMeterBetweenPoints(double aX, double aY, double bX, double bY) {
    double rad = Math.PI / 180;
    int r = 6371;

    double dLat = (aX - bX) * rad;
    double dLng = (aY - bY) * rad;

    double x = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2), 2) + Math.cos(aX * rad) * Math.cos(bX * rad) * Math.pow(Math.sin(dLng / 2), 2);
    double y = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(x), Math.sqrt(1 - x));

    return r * y * 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called [Geofencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-fence). Google already provides such functionality for you. And you don't have to deal with all these complex calculations.

You can fire events when the user entered a specific area / exited a specific area / after staying for some time in a specific area. Or you can make different combinations.

[Here](https://spotandroid.com/2016/12/04/geo-fencing-with-mvp-part-1/) is an article of how you can use Geofencing. It consists of 4 separated articles.